# Gerrit users cannot fetch a visible pending change's ref `refs/changes/06/304506/1`

Tags: git, gerrit

Our gerrit users, including admins, cannot fetch some refs, for example `refs/changes/06/304506/1`. The change `304506` is visible to the user. The user can browse the change on gerrit web. The change can also be queried by the user through ssh commands or restapis. In the server repository, `git for-each-ref` prints the ref `refs/changes/06/304506/1`. However, in the client repository, `git ls-remote` cannot print the ref and `git fetch origin refs/changes/06/304506/1` fails saying `fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/changes/06/304506/1`.

We doubt it's caused by a recent access adjustment, but none of the access changes seems related. As the adjustment is for an important requirment, we cannot simply revert it. Here are the odds that go beyond my knowledge:

1. Even an admin user that is expected to have access to all refs, can only retrieve some of the refs by `git fetch` or `git ls-remote`. If a commit is pushed to `refs/for/foo` and submitted, it can be fetched by `git fetch origin foo`.
2. In the access configuration of all levels, there are no ref patterns about `refs/changes` or refs with numbers. The possible ref pattern is `refs/*`. But to my knowledge, it should affect all refs.
3. We compare the sorted refs produced by `git for-each-ref refs/changes | sort -u` in a server repository, with the sorted refs produced by `git ls-remote | grep refs/changes | sort -u` in a client repository. The refs are naturally grouped by the 3rd segment(`/06/`, which indicates the change number's last 2 digits are `06`). In the same group, it seems only the refs whose 4th segment(`304506`) is bigger than a certain number can be fetched. Due to the limited samples, we cannot find out the specific boundary number. It's around `305xxx`. And there are a few exceptions which are smaller than the boundary but can be fetched. We doubt it's not about which is bigger or smaller but if it matches some pattern.

So far we have tried:

1. Expicility grant the access `read refs/changes/*` or `read refs/changes/06/304506/1` with and without `exclusive` to the admin user.
2. Run `ssh -p 29418 $admin@$gerrithost gerrit index changes 304506`.
3. Clone with `--mirror`.

But none worked. Thanks for any suggestion and help.